# DeLong for C-statistics Cox Regression Models

Tags: r, compare, cox-regression

I've made three Cox Regression models predicting for an outcome. I've the concordence index of all of them, but I want to compare them. In multiple articles, I've read the DeLong's test is the way to go. However, it does not work for me.

If used
`coxph(Surv(daysprim, prim_outcome1)~variable1 + variable2, data= DB)` as the creator of the models.

How can I compare the C-statistics of the different non-nested models?